# How to compile a function whose arguments are lists containing strings?

Tags: compile

I'm unsuccessfully trying to compile this function

```
check[argA_, argB_] := argA[[1]] == argB[[1]];
```

assuming that both arguments argA and argB are of the form

```
{Real, String, ....}
```

Neither

```
cf = Compile[
{
{x, {_Real, _String}, 1},
{y, {_Real, _String}, 1}
},
x[[1]] == y[[1]]
];
```

nor

```
cf = Compile[
{
{x, {_Real, _String}, {1}},
{y, {_Real, _String}, {1}}
},
x[[1]] == y[[1]]
];
```

work as expected, and I can't see the underlying rule. 
I'm grateful for any explaination.

Comment: Can't mix types like that directly (from the docs: "assumes that Subscript[x, i] is a rank Subscript[n, i] array of objects, *each* of a type that matches Subscript[t, i]. " (emphasis mine).

Comment: Strings cannot be compiled.

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57355/is-it-possible-to-compile-the-function-with-string-argument

Comment: You could convert input strings to integers and convert them back to strings in the output of the compiled function, if the strings are not supposed to change in the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @RunnyKine comments, `String` arguments cannot be compiled. From the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html):

> **The types handled by `Compile` are:**
>
> - `_Integer`  machine‐size integer
> - `_Real` machine‐precision approximate real number (default)
> - `_Complex`  machine‐precision approximate complex number
> - `True | False`  logical variable

Comment: SInce version 12.0.0 there is another definition with more detail available in the documentation: [CodeCompilation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CodeCompilation.html) in the section Type specification and [CompiledTypes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CompiledTypes.html) informs about the advanced compilation capabilities for extended type inferencing. There are now compound and functions types added.