# When to use Compile

Tags: compile

I am new to Mathematica and have a general question:

Working with matrices I have the impression that Compile can only be used if
the elements of a matrix are ONLY Integers or ONLY Reals. No mixed types are
allowed.

But my matrices generally include some missing elements like

```
m = {{1., 2.}, {Null, 3.}}
```

Is there a way to compile m*m ?

Comment: Please note that matrix operations are in general very very fast in Mathematica without using Compile. In fact, it is easily possible that you slow something down. Try to use built-in functions first.
Your observation about the types is correct. `Compile` can only handle tensors of one type.. either Real, Integer, ... but mixed types are not possible. The `m` you use is not even compilable!

Comment: @halirutan - thanks, your answer spared me a lot of trials and errors

Answer (score 2):

Quoting a comment by halirutan,

> Please note that matrix operations are in general very very fast in
>   *Mathematica* without using `Compile`. In fact, it is easily possible that
>   you slow something down. Try to use built-in functions first. Your
>   observation about the types is correct. `Compile[]` can only handle
>   tensors of one type.. either `Real`, `Integer`, ... but mixed types are
>   not possible ([a reference is here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46901/how-to-compile-a-function-whose-arguments-are-lists-containing-strings)). The `m` you use is not even compilable!