# Is it possible to Compile the function with string argument?

Tags: string-manipulation, compile

As we can see from the [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html) documentation, the typical arguments for `Compile` should be `Integer`, `Real`, `Complex` and `True` | `False`:

[image]

Is it possible to use a `String` as argument type for `Compile`?

May be somebody knows a tricky way?

I met with task to read the data remotely from oscilloscope and it can send it just as huge, long  strings. So I need convert it after to numerical form. It is not a problem but it needs a lot of time if that string contains 5-6 thousands of chars.

Comment: There's a risk someone will prove me wrong, but I believe that no, you can't use a string in compiled functions.  You can convert to character codes and work with those.

Comment: Even if you could specify `_String`(and I don't believe you can), I'm pretty sure that none of the `String*` functions are [compilable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096/list-of-compilable-functions), so you wouldn't really be getting any benefit from the compiled function(it would just be making a call-back to top-level).  What sort of operation are you doing on these strings?

Comment: Nick, These strings are numbers separated by spaces, I need parse it to take the numbers.  And additionally I need to change exponential form from xxxE-yy to understandable for MM form. 
I already did such converter but I need to speed up it.